# What became of ggsave (ggplot 0.6.8) in later versions of ggplot python

Tags: python-3.x, python-ggplot

In version 0.6.8 I use ggsave() from ggplot in Python.
In version 0.11 such a function does not exist. Which one should I use to replace it?

This is the code that used to work in previous version:

```
import ggplot as gg
plot_data = gg.ggplot(dat, gg.aes('month', 'average_workers')) + gg.geom_line() + gg.scale_y_continuous(breaks=11) + \
            gg.scale_x_discrete(breaks=list_of_years_division, labels=list_of_years) + \
            gg.ggtitle('Evolution of average numbers of workers per firm, monthly\nAgents : %s' %
                       title_pop_val+'% of Population') + gg.xlab('Years') + gg.ylab('Units') + gg.theme_bw()

gg.ggsave(plot_data, os.path.join(parameters.output_data_path, ('temp_general_average_workers%s.png' %
                                                               parameters.parameters_names)))
```

plot_data is a ggplot object.
I have tried:

```
gg.ggplot.save(plot_data, 'path.jpg', 10, 6, 300)
```

And the error I get is:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: I cannot find any documentation, but some pretty examples...

Comment: I also tried `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`and then `p = plt.gcf(); p.savefig('t.png')`. The plot came out empty.

Comment: Still unsolved!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. It looks like the solution is to call 'save()' on the ggplot object:

```
plot_data.save(filename='path.png')
```